# Select all siblings (including text) of comment in xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have an XML document, a fragment line of which could look like this:

```
<p>Some text <!--a comment --> some more text <b>some bold text</b> something else etc</p>
```

I would like to select the comment based on its text, but also all following "sibling" elements. In this example, I know I can get the comment with '//comment()[. = "a comment"]'.

How can I get the result: " some more text **some bold text** something else etc"? (the remainder of the siblings inside the paragraph tag)

In case it makes any difference, I'm using python and etree to parse.

EDIT:

My test XML in full:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<p>A paragraph<!--A comment--><b>test</b>A line break</p>
</root>
```

My test XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select='//comment()/following-sibling::node()'/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

or, in Python, using lxml, just a "None" object.

EDIT #2:

My bad -- the accepted answer works well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all siblings including other comments:

```xml
//comment()[.="a comment "]/following-sibling::node()
```

For example:

```
>>> xml.xpath('//comment()[.="a comment "]/following-sibling::node()')
[' some more text ', <Element b at 0x2923af0>, ' ', <!-- other comment -->, ' something else etc']
```

I added an additional comment but otherwise used your input data.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I need to select only items /after/ the specific comment, though. (I haven't yet had any luck using the comment as a preceding node.)

Comment: Thanks, although I am going a little crazy because that's exactly what I was trying. Edited above to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Actually, my apologies -- I was being slow at the end of the day -- this works fine!